# Terraform: Run provisioner on deposed resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have two AWS resources managed by Terraform:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "default" {}
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "default" {
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I recently set `create_before_destroy = true` since my goal is to have minimal/zero downtime when migrating the cluster to a new node group. I was able to achieve *less* downtime with this change, but I'd like to migrate the pods (and ensure all of them are running) on the old node group to the new one before the old node group is deleted, thus achieving zero downtime. I already have an idea of how I'd write that script, but my question is how to run it at the right time.

Running `terraform apply` creates a deposed resource before it is deleted when `create_before_destroy` is set to `true`. I'd like to get the list of nodes in the old node group (the deposed resource) and run my script before it gets deleted. What would that look like in Terraform?

Comment: Have you seen destroy time provisioners? Also, it doesn't answer this exact question but there are different/maybe better ways of achieving this same thing such as https://github.com/aws/aws-node-termination-handler. This also allows the ASG to be drained in the event of a scale in event or, when deployed in queue processing mode, to handle spot instance interruptions etc as well as when you want to replace the ASG.

Comment: Hmmm... actually, now that I think about it I think managed node groups already do automatic draining of nodes before deletion? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html seems to suggest so too. We're not using managed node groups yet for some other reasons so could be wrong here but have you checked if you even need to do anything here?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The impression I got from destroy-time provisioners is that they were run _after_ the resource was destroyed, not before. Previously, I was looking for something like a "before-destroy" provisioner but had no luck. When I change out the node group, all of the pods are terminated before they are spun up. I'll look into that node-termination handler you posted in your comment. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#destroy-time-provisioners `Destroy provisioners are run before the resource is destroyed`. You shouldn't need the node termination handler with managed node groups. The default behaviour for managed node groups should be to drain the instances before terminating them which means all the pods should be restarted by the replicaset on new nodes before they are evicted. If you're seeing something different to that with managed node groups you should talk to AWS support.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Oh, it helps if I read more than the first sentence in the docs. The first sentence they use in that section sounds contradictory then: "If when = destroy is specified, the provisioner will run _when the resource it is defined within is destroyed_." That to me implies that it is _after_, but as you point out, the next sentence they say is _before_. I guess that's the solution to my problem then. If you'd like, you can put that as the answer to this question.

Comment: I Just went through this same thing. You need pod disruption budgets and `create_before_destroy` should be sufficient. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/

Comment: Sorry, that's not all I did. I also added a `when = destroy` local-exec provisioner to the node groups to execute a script to drain the nodes via `kubectl`.